# USB3.0 port is not working

Tags: 16.04, usb, usb-drive, bios

I have a Lenovo Ideapad dual boot. USB3.0 port is working fine in Windows 10 but not in Ubuntu 16.04 (USB2.0 is working fine).

When I insert pendrive in USB2.0, it shows in Files (file explorer) but not in case of USB3.0

Do I need to install a driver for it or enable it from somewhere?

Here are the ouputs of [dmesg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25337091/) and [lsusb -v and lsusb](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25337102/)

Kernel version: 4.10

BIOS version: 1TCN22WW (V2.03)

Comment: according to dmesg the xhci_hcd (USB 3.0) driver is working and detects devices

Comment: As above^. Please define "not working".

Comment: Defined. Please check now.

Comment: @SuiciDoga  please reply

Comment: there aren't any errors in dmesg but lsusb -v says can't open device. can you try running it as root ?

Comment: also the dmesg says you have a mouse plugged in via usb 3.0 does it work ?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed. The mouse works fine.  Maybe it doesn't support / not enabled USB 3.0?